# Python Scipy dblquad function giving wrong answer on short range

Tags: python, scipy

I want to integrate the following double integral:

[image: Definite integral to be computed]

I want to use the dblquad method from the scipy.integrate package, which allows you to do double integrals with limits of the inner integral as a function of the outer integral variable:

```
import scipy.integrate as spi
import numpy as np

x_limit = 0
y_limit = lambda x: np.arccos(np.cos(x))

integrand = lambda x, y: np.exp(-(2+np.cos(x)-np.cos(y)))
low_limit_y = 0              # inner integral
up_limit_y = y_limit
low_limit_x = x_limit        # outer integral
up_limit_x = 2*np.pi-x_limit

integral = spi.dblquad(integrand, low_limit_x, up_limit_x, low_limit_y, up_limit_y)

print(integral)
```

Output:

```
(0.6934912861906996, 2.1067956428653226e-12)
```

The code runs, but does not give me the right answer. Using Wolfram Alpha I get the right answer: 3.58857

[Wolfram Alpha method](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=double+integral+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangeend2%22%7D+-%3E%22arccos%28cos%28x%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangeend1%22%7D+-%3E%222pi%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22integrand%22%7D+-%3E%22exp%28-%282%2Bcos%28x%29-cos%28y%29%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable1%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangestart1%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable2%22%7D+-%3E%22y%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangestart2%22%7D+-%3E%220%22)

The only thing I've noticed is that the values from the two methods agree when the signs on the cosines are switched from + to - and vice versa:

[Wolfram Alpha method with signs on the cosines swapped](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=double%20integral%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangeend2%22%7D%20-%3E%22arccos%28cos%28x%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangeend1%22%7D%20-%3E%222pi%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22integrand%22%7D%20-%3E%22exp%28-%282-cos%28x%29%2Bcos%28y%29%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22intvariable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangestart1%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22intvariable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22y%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangestart2%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22)

However, I have no plausible reason for why this should be the case. Does anyone have any clue what is going on here? I can separate the function out into the inner integral looping over all values of x and then summing the results which gives the right answer, but that is really quite slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take another look at the docstring of `dblquad`; it says

```
Return the double (definite) integral of ``func(y, x)`` from ``x = a..b``
and ``y = gfun(x)..hfun(x)``.
```

Note the order of arguments of `func(y, x)`: `y` first, then `x`.

If you change your definition of `integrand` to

```
integrand = lambda y, x: np.exp(-(2+np.cos(x)-np.cos(y)))
```

you get the expected answer.  That is also (in effect) what you did when you changed the signs of the `cos` terms in the integrand.

(You're not the first one to get tripped up by the expected order of the arguments to `func`.)

Comment: Thanks so much! I triple checked the docs and boundaries, but must have completely missed that part in the doc.