# scipy dblquad seems to give a wrong answer

Tags: python, scipy

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.integrate import dblquad
from scipy.integrate import nquad # n dimensional integral

def f(t,p):
  return np.sin(t) * np.exp( -760.45332604428756 *( -  (1.0 * 0.001) *  np.sin(t)*  np.cos(p) +   (-10 * 0.001/2) *  np.sin(t)**2 + (10 * 0.001/2)* np.sin(t)**2 * np.sin(p)**2 )   )

area = dblquad(f,   0,np.pi,   -np.pi/2,np.pi/2)
print("area = ",area)
```

gives   area =  (6.355113632868125e-16, 2.1352999812415674e-07)

Now, I use Wolfram Alpha

```
Integrate [   Sin[t] Exp[ -  760.45332604428756  ( -  (1.0 * 0.001)  Sin[t] Cos[p ] +   (-10 * 0.001/2) Sin[t]^2 + (10 * 0.001/2) Sin[t]^2 Sin[p]^2 )  ], {t,0, Pi}, {p, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
```

that gives a correct integral of 83.9147.

What is wrong with my python script?

Comment: I remember having this problem before, try look at the function you pass into ``dblquad`` and its signature - specifically the dependent and the independent variable order. I think that was the solution for me

Comment: See ["Python Scipy dblquad function giving wrong answer on short range"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69753690/python-scipy-dblquad-function-giving-wrong-answer-on-short-range)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [scipy docs on dblquad, on parameter f](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html):

> A Python function or method of at least two variables: **y must be the first argument and x the second argument.**

Edit: Just checked it myself, swapping the parameters of the `f()` function (now `def f(p,t):`) results in
`area =(83.95467263236071, 1.8660742284737353e-07)`

Comment: @Ed Gan please accept my answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: Thank you Sasszem. I might have wasted many hours trying to find out the true cause. The order of arguments in the list is really counter intuitive. It is  (x,y, limit of y, limit of x) weird sequence. I suggest scipy fixes this by a brand new dblquad to be resigned and renamed something else.